# Rounding to different decimal places using a GUI output box

Tags: java, user-interface, rounding

I know this is a simple task, but I think I'm just having trouble with the formatting. I can get the GUI input box to ask for a number with 8 decimal places, but for the output box I can't figure out how to round the number the user input to 5 and 3 decimal places. This is what I'm stuck on:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Ch3Assignment6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String Decimal_Eight = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter a decimal number with eight decimal places");         


        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, 
        "The number you entered is: " + Decimal_Eight + "\n" + 
        "The number rounded to 5 decimal places is: " + String.format("%.5f", Decimal_Eight) + "\n" + 
        "The number rounded to 3 decimal places is: " + String.format("%.3f", Decimal_Eight));

    }

}
```

It shows an error message/no output message box but i don't know how i'm entering the rounding part incorrectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The String format you applied works on floating points, not on Strings. Try to parse it to a double first:

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a decimal number with eight decimal places");
double Decimal_Eight = Double.parseDouble(input);
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer; hello, please which one would be faster if needed inside a loop to `addElement` to a `JList` modal, thanx

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @MartijinCourteaux answer (+1), you can also use the `NumberFormat` class directly to make adjustments to how a number is formatted...

```
double value = 123.4567890123456789;
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(5);
System.out.println(nf.format(value));
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);
System.out.println(nf.format(value));
```

Which outputs...

```
123.45679
123.457
```

Now, obviously, I've started with a `double`, if you have `String`, you would only need to following @MartijnCourteaux answer to parse the value to a `double`...

Comment: @Martijn Courteaux; hello, please which one would be faster if needed inside a loop to `addElement` to a `JList` modal, thanx

Comment: @Scaramouche I would store the number value in the `ListModel` and use a `ListCellRenderer` to renderer it

Comment: thanks, I'll check into that `ListCellRenderer` but, is this way off for now: `model.addElement(nf.format(ticket.getCosto()));` or `model.addElement(String.format("%.2f", ticket.getCosto()));` inside a for loop?  which one would be better? it is rendering the values... (`nf` is a properly configured `NumberFormat`)

Comment: @Scaramouche I doubt it would matter, I'd personally use `NumberFormatter` as it will give better rounding results (AFAIK)